# Is every field closed under integer multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reading through Gallian's proof that the characteristic of an integral domain is either 0 or prime. The proof relies on the fact that for two integers $s$ and $t$ $(s \cdot 1)$ and $(t \cdot 1)$ are in our general integral domain. This just seemed a bit strange to me and I am trying to make sense of it.

Comment: "$(s \cdot 1)$" means "$\underbrace{1+1+\cdots +1}_{s\text{ times}}$".  In fact, "how many ones do you add together to get zero" is more or less the definition of characteristic (with a caveat for the case "infinitely many").  So we don't ask that you can multiply by an integer, we only ask that you can (set theoretically) count $s$ copies of $1$, then add them together, which you can do in any ring with $1$.

Comment: Another way to think about the same thing: any ring $R$ with unit $1_R$ admits a unique ring homomorphism (respecting $1$'s) from $\Bbb{Z}.$ If this map is $\iota_R : \Bbb{Z}\to R,$ you can think of $s\cdot 1_R$ and $t\cdot 1_R$ as shorthand for $\iota_R(s)\cdot 1_R$ and $\iota_R(t)\cdot 1_R$, respectively.

Comment: Alternatively, if you know about modules, then the map $\iota_R$ gives $R$ the structure of a $\Bbb{Z}$-module. In particular, this means that there is an action of $\Bbb{Z}$ on $R$; or in other words, a map $a : \Bbb{Z}\times R\to R$ which needs to satisfy certain properties. With this point of view, $s\cdot 1_R$ is $a(s,1_R),$ but this is really defined by setting $a(s,1_R) = \iota_R(s)\cdot 1_R,$ so this is no more nor less than what I spelled out in my previous comment.

Comment: And of course, these are both exactly the same as what Eric Towers says in his comment, since $$\iota_R(s) = \iota_R(\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{s\textrm{ times}}) = \underbrace{\iota_R(1) + \cdots + \iota_R(1)}_{s\textrm{ times}} = \underbrace{1_R+\dots+1_R}_{s\textrm{ times}}$$ by the properties of ring homomorphisms.

Comment: @Stahl why don't you make this an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to think about this.

The first way to think about this is outlined in Eric Towers' comment above. In any commutative ring $R$ (with or without unity), we may define $n\cdot r$ for $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ positive and $r\in R$ as
$$
n\cdot r = \underbrace{r + r + \dots + r}_{n\textrm{ times}}.
$$
Since addition in a ring is associative, the right hand side is well defined. We extend this to all $n$ in $\Bbb{Z}$ by setting $0\cdot r = 0_R$ and $$n\cdot r = \underbrace{(-r) + (-r) + \dots + (-r)}_{-n\textrm{ times}}$$ for $n < 0.$

The observant reader may notice that none of what we did here requires the ring structure on $R.$ In fact, the above makes sense in any abelian group.

Now, if $R$ is a ring with unity $1_R,$ we may say a little more. Any ring with unity receives a unique ring homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}$ which sends $1\in\Bbb{Z}$ to $1_R$ in $R$ (check this!). Let's call this homomorphism $\iota_R : \Bbb{Z}\to R.$ Then for $n\in\Bbb{Z},$ $n\cdot 1_R$ may be thought of as simply shorthand for $\iota_R(n)\cdot 1_R.$ Both $\iota_R(n)$ and $1_R$ are in $R,$ so this makes sense without any additional work.

Another way to think about all the above, which is really only a change of language, is that any ring (or even any abelian group) is a $\Bbb{Z}$-module. This means that there is a function
$$
a : \Bbb{Z}\times R\to R
$$
which must satisfy a few additional properties. In this language, $n\cdot 1_R$ is simply $a(n,1_R),$ which is by definition $\underbrace{1_R + \dots + 1_R}_{n\textrm{ times}}$ (or $\iota_R(n)\cdot 1_R,$ if your ring has a unit). More generally, any ring homomorphism $\phi : R\to S$ will give the ring $S$ the structure of an $R$-module, by defining $r\cdot s = \phi(r)\cdot s$ for $r\in R$ and $s\in S.$

With that, we come right back to the start -- all of these perspectives are really very little other than a change of language!

Comment: "all of these perspectives are really very little other than a change of language!" And that's the entirety of mathematics in a single sentence.....